# How to find distance covered by rectangle google map

Tags: php, google-maps, distance

I have draw a rectangle in google map using drawing manager 
how can i find distance covered by rectangle in Km or miles .

please help me

Comment: you can calculate the distance between two geopoints by a simple math operation. so search with get distance between two geopoints in google map

Comment: Not distance between two geopoints in google map  ,its a rectangle

Comment: bro rectangle is made by for geopoints get distance one by one and sum of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `Distance` between two `Geopoints` in `KM`

```
function distanceGeoPoints ($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2) {

    $earthRadius = 3958.75;

    $dLat = deg2rad($lat2-$lat1);
    $dLng = deg2rad($lng2-$lng1);


    $a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) +
       cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) *
       sin($dLng/2) * sin($dLng/2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a));
    $dist = $earthRadius * $c;

    // from miles
    $meterConversion = 1609;
    $kilometerConversion = 1.609;
    $geopointDistance = $dist * $kilometerConversion;

    return $geopointDistance;
}
```

Now Suppose that you have a rectangle which has four points(A, B, C, D)

```
A __________________________ D    
 |                          |
 |                          |
 |                          |
 |__________________________|  
B                            C
```

So your distance will be

```
Total distance = 2 * ((distance between A and B) + (distance between A and D))
```